# Prevent direct access to a PDF on a PHP secured website

Tags: php, .htaccess

I created a PHP website with login and users have access to PDF files.
How can I prevent unauthorized users from accessing the PDF files via direct link?

I tried with .htaccess but "deny from all allow from localhost" also blocks my logged users. I tried with RewriteEngine and it allows all even if i delete the line with empty referer :

```
# ultimate hotlink protection
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$           [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^https?://([^.]+\.)?domain\. [NC]
 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$                             - [F,NC,L]
</ifModule>
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

if all you want is that only login users can download a pdf file:
In your html page, you put for example this link:

```
<a href:'download.php'>Download now!</a>
```

and then create a php file like this:

download.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["IdUser"])) {
    header("location:goToHell.php");
} 
else {
    $file="yourPath/theFile.pdf";

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `pdf` in your blocked list:

```
# ultimate hotlink protection
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^https?://([^.]+\.)?domain\. [NC]
 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png|pdf)$ - [F,NC,L]
</ifModule>
```

However keep in mind that blocking based on `HTTP_REFERER` is not 100% secured as clients can send a custom `HTTP_REFERER` header also.

Comment: I added pdf in the list locally, I just copy-pasted the code from the source, it doesn't work. What are the other options I have to secure those files?

Comment: Other options is to keep pdf file outside `DocumentRoot` and read the pdf content from your PHP code.

Comment: I would like to keep the documents where they are if possible and use htaccess to only allow users that come from "domain/document_access.php?id=something" Is that possible ?

Comment: That solution is already there, you need to explain why it doesn't work for you.